# laravel terminable middleware - is it processed after the response has been sent to the browser?

Tags: php, laravel

according to the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware#terminable-middleware) on terminable middleware:

> If you define a terminate method on your middleware, it will automatically be called after the response is ready to be sent to the
>   browser.

The wording seems unclear to me. Will code in my `terminate` method have an effect on my response time?

Answer (score 0):

Middleware is terminated by [`index.php`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/321d9e3786bfd605fe847e34687ccfa8def5bda2/public/index.php#L60) after the response is sent to the browser.

By "sent to the browser", it means the `header()` function has been called to set appropriate headers, and the body output has been `echo`ed.

> Will code in my `terminate` method have an effect on my response time?

**Yes.** Even though `header()` and `echo` have been called, the browser doesn't render the output until the PHP script has fully completed. Login in your terminable middleware *will* affect page load speed.

Answer (score -2):

I haven't practically experimented it. But based on the documentation, it is a "BEFORE" function where you can inspect fully prepared response object BEFORE response is sent out.

And yes, its processing time adds to response time.